# Blazemeter mobile Recorder

Tags: performance, mobile, jmeter, blazemeter

I need your help regarding the Blazemeter Mobile Recorder process.

> I am following the below steps:
>
> 1. Login to BlazeMeter account.
> 2. Go to mobile recorder URL:  http://a.blazemeter.com/app/recorder/index.html
> 3. Create a proxy server
> 4. Turn on WIFI connection. Go to phone’s ‘Settings’, go to 'WIFI' and click on local WIFI network. Check 'show advanced options' and go to
>      the HTTP Proxy.
> 5. Enter data for the server and the port created by Blazemeter recorder.
> 6. Open your mobile browser and enter the following URL: http://bz
> 7. Install the certificate for Android
> 8. Click on Recording button

But after this the Internet on my Mobile device doesn’t works.
Thus I am not able to proceed. Request you to please help me with this.

Thanks,
Chetali

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a local issue with your device's configuration.

We've checked that the proxy servers as well as the Certificates are all valid and working accordingly.

You can check for yourself if you'll enter the Proxy configuration on your computer's browser (preferably firefox) and see that its working well.

I suggest that you carefully go over the [instructions in this article](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Recorder-Mobile-Recorder-) and make sure that you are manually setting up the proxy as it is provided. Also i suggest to terminate the current proxy your've started [on our recorder](https://a.blazemeter.com/app/recorder/index.html#/desktop), generate a new server and try them.

If any further issues occur its probably an issue with your device's connectivity.